# Difference between mirror modifier and creating collection instance

Tags: modeling, modifiers, instances, collections, mirror-modifier

I was wondering about the difference between using the mirror modifier to mirror an object around the main object, and creating a collection instance then rotating the duplicates around the main object.

Is there a certain use cases for each method?.

Can I mirror parented objects together the same way as duplicating them with collection instance?

Comment: it depends if your object is symmetrical or not.

Comment: I guess it depends on the case, could you please describe your object, scene and project?

Comment: Mirror modifier can make continuous surfaces, merge vertex, can clip geometry, and deal with UVs, goof for characters and single symmetrical objects. Collection instance performance optimized by nature by recycling geometry, and can symmetrize independent groups of objects, but not create single surfaces

Comment: Well, one of the main differences is a _Mirror_ modifier mirrors the underlying geometry of a single object (a mesh or curve), which you can change in _Edit Mode_, and as the name says it "mirrors", so everything gets flipped. And no matter how many separate meshes there might be, a _Mirror_ modifier is working on a single object. Whereas a collection instance can hold many different types of objects and works in _Object Mode_. You cannot change the underlying geometry of the objects in _Edit Mode_ directly in the instanced collection, you have to change them in the original collection.

Comment: Thank you all, your comments was really helpful and informative .